# AWS credentials not found in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, refile

I'm deploying a rails app to production using the refile gem for file uploads and connecting to s3 for storage. Everything works great in development I'm getting the following error in production when trying to upload a new image or retrieve an existing one:

```
E, [2015-01-30T16:59:02.841941 #29551] ERROR -- : Refile::App: Error -> 
Missing Credentials.

Unable to find AWS credentials.  You can configure your AWS credentials
a few different ways:

* Call AWS.config with :access_key_id and :secret_access_key

* Export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ENV

* On EC2 you can run instances with an IAM instance profile and credentials
  will be auto loaded from the instance metadata service on those
  instances.

* Call AWS.config with :credential_provider.  A credential provider should
  either include AWS::Core::CredentialProviders::Provider or respond to
  the same public methods.

= Ruby on Rails

In a Ruby on Rails application you may also specify your credentials in
the following ways:

* Via a config initializer script using any of the methods mentioned above
  (e.g. RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb).

* Via a yaml configuration file located at RAILS_ROOT/config/aws.yml.
  This file should be formated like the default RAILS_ROOT/config/database.yml
  file.

E, [2015-01-30T16:59:02.842423 #29551] ERROR -- : Refile::App: /home/deploy/real_org/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.60.2/lib/aws/core/credential_providers.rb:140:in `credentials'
```

I have configured the credentials in the RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb file like so

```
require 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config(access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"])
```

And I have confirmed that the env variables exist by typing

```
$: echo $AWS_SECRET_KEY

$: echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

which returns the keys properly. Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Comment: Check here for a walk-through - maybe it will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443923/how-to-set-up-amazon-s3-paperclip-and-env-variables

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the production keys are also set. Production and development are two different environments. If you have deployed to something like heroku, you will have to set those either manually or with the help of something like the figaro gem that Brad mentioned.

Here are some resources

http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/managing-environment-configuration-variables-in-rails

Comment: I think I have al the keys set properly - I can actually do image uploads to S3 via Refile in the console. I can't seem to duplicate the problem in the console, wondering if that helps to look in another direction.